# Valet PHP-FPM and Nginx Errors - Upstream Closed Connection, Child Process SIGSEGV, and Database Access Issue

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, nginx, valet

I'm experiencing issues with Laravel Valet on my macOS system. When I check the logs, I see some errors related to PHP-FPM and Nginx. Here are the logs:

**PHP-FPM Log:**

```
[01-Aug-2023 09:13:04] WARNING: [pool valet] child 79760 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 3.751510 seconds from start [01-Aug-2023 09:13:04] NOTICE: [pool valet] child 79768 started
```

**Nginx Log**

```
2023/08/01 08:56:36 [error] 73231#0: *28 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: gmreproducciones.test, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/juliofranco/.config/valet/valet.sock:", host: "gmreproducciones.test" 2023/08/01 09:13:04 [error] 73231#0: *35 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: gmreproducciones.test, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: 
"fastcgi://unix:/Users/juliofranco/.config/valet/valet.sock:", host: "gmreproducciones.test"
```

**System Info:**

- macOS BigSur 11.7.9
- PHP version: 8.2.8 (cli)
- Valet version: Laravel Valet 4.1.3
- Laravel Framework version: 9.52.12
- Using PHP version linked in valet: php@8.2

**Issue:**
I'm encountering three distinct errors. First, PHP-FPM is experiencing a SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) error, and its child process is terminating unexpectedly. Second, Nginx is showing "upstream prematurely closed connection" errors when accessing my website, resulting in a 502 Bad Gateway error. Third, I'm facing an issue with database access using Valet. Database Access Issue: When trying to access the database (PostgreSQL@14) through Valet, the website fails with the mentioned Nginx errors. However, I've verified that database connections work fine when testing them directly. Additionally, if I run php artisan serve within my project, the database connection is successful, and I don't experience any issues.

**Configuration:** I have Valet using PHP version 8.2. My brew services list shows that dnsmasq, httpd, and postgresql@14 are running fine. However, Nginx and PHP-FPM are showing errors. My Nginx configuration seems to be pointing to the correct socket file (valet.sock) for PHP-FPM. Troubleshooting Attempted: I have restarted Valet and PHP-FPM, but the issue persists. I verified that my PHP and Laravel Valet versions are compatible. Checked Nginx configuration and logs, but couldn't find any issues related to the errors. Reviewed the logs but couldn't determine the root cause.

I expect Valet, PHP-FPM, and Nginx to work correctly, and the website to have successful database access without 502 Bad Gateway errors. Can someone help me identify and resolve the issues with PHP-FPM, Nginx, and database access through Valet?

Answer (score 7):

In `/usr/local/etc/php/8.2/php-fpm.d/www.conf` after the following:

```
; Pass environment variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH. All $VARIABLEs are taken from
; the current environment.
; Default Value: clean env
;env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
;env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
;env[TMP] = /tmp
;env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
;env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

Add an environment variable like this:

```
env['PGGSSENCMODE'] = disable
```

Then restart php. This will work even after a reboot.

Tested this working in php 8.2 and 7.4.

UPDATE: If you're using laravel/valet the file should be `/usr/local/etc/php/8.2/php-fpm.d/valet-fpm.conf`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to Valet?

Comment: It's related to php, I'm using Homebrew, for valet the file should be `/usr/local/etc/php/8.2/php-fpm.d/valet-fpm.conf`

Comment: In my case, it works by adding 

PGGSSENCMODE=disable

in my .env of my Laravel app.   Adding this environment variable to /usr/local/etc/php/8.2/php-fpm.d/valet-fpm.conf didn't anything.

Comment: Got this problem after PHP Monitor upgrade. Thank you for the fix

Answer (score 1):

I fall on the same problem yesterday. I am using PHP Monitor and I have provided **First Aid & Services > Fix My Valet...** and **First Aid & Services > Restore Homebrew Permissions** respectively.
Fixed. However, if it doesn't work for you, I suggest you completely uninstall valet and reinstall it and restart your local servers.

Comment: Thank you, it solves my php monitor problem on my laptop with Monterey, since phpmon is not compatible with BigSur. I had the same error on both operating systems and it took me almost 22 days to get to this solution. Very thankful. I have added two tools to improve my management, Herd and PGAdmin4.

Comment: Something that could also help is that in the valet documentation, it clarifies that in versions greater than 10.14 macOS no longer allows projects to be in Desktop, Document and Download, unless you allow it from System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy and selecting Full Disk Access. Next, enable any nginx entries in the main window pane.

Comment: Also useful issue: https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/1433#issuecomment-1655883465

Comment: I have a similar issue, but all fixes so far don't seem to have worked. My CMS runs multiple sites from one code base, and have an issue with the front of one site only. All other sites work as expected, but this particular one returns:

Nginx Log:

    `2023/09/07 14:11:23 [error] 28936#0: *142 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: accurate-armour.test, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/iantearle/.config/valet/valet.sock:", host: "accurate-armour.test"`

Comment: Turns out ngettext() is causing the 502 error. But, still I have no idea why, or why it would suddenly start doing so.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed since Valet 6.0:

More info: https://github.com/laravel/valet/pull/1452