# 502 Bad Gateway on certain API Calls (Laravel, Valet, nginx)

Tags: laravel, nginx, valet

I'm encounter an error on my Laravel installations on my computer. On certain calls (with payloads, with bearer token, ecc.) i recieve a "502 Bad Gateway" error. This is my configuration:

- MacOS 12.6.8
- Valet 4.4.0
- PHP 8.1
- Laravel 8.12
- nginx 1.25.2

Every other website served by Valet works perfectly via browser; If i create a test route with a simple string print api call works (in every Laravel installations). But if i use standard call with Request and Response nginx of Valet log this error:

`[error] 6601#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/MY_USER/.config/valet/valet.sock:", host: "MY_WEBSITE.test"`

I didn't change anythings of my laravel source code in the meanwhile, but probably changed somethings in my configuration. The only task I perform was an update of PHP and Valet, but I was rollback to previous configuration without resolve the problem.
I tried some workaround, like upgrade cgi buffer size, reinstalling the entire stack from scratch, but without resolve.

Anyone can help me to suggest some other checks?
Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I checked my valet installation (valet uninstall, valet install, tried "Fix My Valet" );
I checked php-fpm, php and laravel logs but nothings logged;
I checked nginx log and my only message is the same i had posted in my first message;
I increased both php memory limit and fastcgi buffer;
all databases and websites in valet parked folder works;
if i creare a simple laravel enpoint with a simple "test" string printed and it works
found where app crashes in a 502 error. When I perform an Eloquent function. So it's limited to those actions.

So, to recap my situation:
**

- If I try the same function (e.g.: Card::find(1)) in thinker session it works perfectly
- if a try a test API call (eg.: a simple test call with a string as response) it works perfectly
- if I navigate su app via browser it works perfectly
- if I try a Api call to a function of a controller where I have to perform an Eloquent query (e.g.: Card::find(1)) it responds with a 502 Bad Gateway error (with Nginx log "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server:").**

Comment: - Tried to call function via tinker and it works perfectly
- Also tried to update to Laravel 9.x, but same error

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet... I will try to migrate from Laravel 9.x to Laravel 10.x... it's frustrating

Comment: Hey, just thought I would leave this here for you in case you're still having problems. This is what fixed it for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76812272/valet-php-fpm-and-nginx-errors-upstream-closed-connection-child-process-sigse

Best of luck!

Comment: @RogyBear, which of two solutions works for you? env['PGGSSENCMODE'] = disable or First Aid & Services > Fix My Valet... and First Aid & Services > Restore Homebrew Permissions. Because I already tried the second one, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: @RogyBear I tried the first solution right now and I resolved the problem! thanks alot for your help! your save my day!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Valet PHP-FPM and Nginx Errors - Upstream Closed Connection, Child Process SIGSEGV, and Database Access Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76812272/valet-php-fpm-and-nginx-errors-upstream-closed-connection-child-process-sigse)